# React-native android studio Build Failed

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

When I do build->rebuild project the build fails in the android studio. I have the error message posted below. This is very strange because I didn't change anything, all I tried was to create a new AVD and the next thing you know trying to build it causes an error. Now I can't get it to run. I am hesitant to try some random quick fix because everything was working fine until I created a new AVD.

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/waltershub/Desktop/Fluz-Develop/fluzfluz-frontend/fluzclient/android/app/src/main/java/com/fluzclient/MainApplication.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
import io.branch.referral.Branch;
                         ^
  symbol:   class Branch
  location: package io.branch.referral
/Users/waltershub/Desktop/Fluz-Develop/fluzfluz-frontend/fluzclient/android/app/src/main/java/com/fluzclient/MainApplication.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
    Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
    ^
  symbol:   variable Branch
  location: class MainApplication
Note: /Users/waltershub/Desktop/Fluz-Develop/fluzfluz-frontend/fluzclient/android/app/src/main/java/com/fluzclient/MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.0-milestone-1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 19s
409 actionable tasks: 381 executed, 28 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 0):

**Branch SDK** is not properly imported in your React project.

https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/react-native/

Follow YARN installation to add dependencies in the project.